# Empty Image was saved on server

Tags: php, wampserver

i need your help...i want to copy/upload images on server and saving directories in database...Problem is the images are empty =(
I'm using:

- WampServer
- Apache Version : 2.2.22
- PHP Version : 5.3.13
- MySQL  Version : 5.5.24

Issue is that it's creating the file but is empty.... can it be WampServer fault?

CODE:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000">
<input name="image" id="image" multiple="true" type="file" />
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="Enter Image Name" class="text-field"/>


if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['image']))
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $img = $_POST['image'];

        $file_url = $img;
        $fp = fopen($file_url, 'rb');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($file_url));
        $fp = fopen('../Images/UploadedImages/'.$img, 'wb');
        $image='../Images/UploadedImages/'.$img;

        $result=mysql_query("insert into Images(Name,Directory,Register_Day) 
        values ('$name','$image',now())");

        if (!$result) {
            die("Failed to load");}
        else{
            fputs($fp, $content);
            fclose($fp);
            }
```

Comment: Note that your `fclose($fp);` should be outside the `if` block. Also, are entries being put into your database?

Comment: is $file_url an absolute path of an existing file on your server? if not then you have to upload a file with an upload-form-element

Comment: I want to save image.jpg to dir ../Images/UploadedImages/ and in database will be ../Images/UploadedImages/image.jpg ... in future i'll read from db and <img src='$row[0]'/> ... something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant upload image by using `fopen`. Try below code.
Your will get image details in `$_FILES` array not in `$_POST`.

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['image']["name"];
$uploads_dir = '../Images/UploadedImages';
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

In above code `$uploads_dir/$name` will be your image path which you can store in db.

And also make sure that your `<form>` tag has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set.

Comment: it works thank you....only problem now is to increase availability to upload bigger images)

Answer (score 1):

Uloading images doesn't work like that, you must do something like this:

```
$img = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
```

Also note that you don't want to save the image into the database, you (probably) want to save the image to the server but you save only the file location into the database.

Comment: I didn't spot that - from the PHP I assumed the OP was expecting urls not files.